# Remove a Visual Studio project from TFS project list

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

Some OCD aspects of my personality are rearing up as I "need" to remove this Console Application from the Explorer tab in Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online). I have removed this project from the last commit / push but it's still there and slowly driving me crazy.

[image]

I'm using the git type of repository. Happy to learn a command or 2 to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the folder from within Visual Studio / Team Explorer (Ctrl+\, Ctrl+M) / Source Control Explorer?

In either the tree on the left or the main section in the middle, right click the folder and select "delete". Then commit your changes.